# Using CursorLoader to retrieve only UNIQUE values from SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, android-cursorloader

I have a list that is meant to retrieve the cities that are associated with an item in my sqlite database. I am able to retrieve a list that contains a row for each contact and displays its respective city. Most of the items share the same city so instead I am seeking to retrieve a list of **each unique** city so that below I can indicate how many items share this same city.

My provider looks like below

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
        case LOADER_ID:
            return new CursorLoader(
                    getContext(),
                    DatabaseDescription.Flowers.CONTENT_URI,
                    FROM_COLUMNS,
                    COLUMN_LOCATION + "<> ''",
                    null,
                    COLUMN_LOCATION + " ASC"
            );
        default:
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("no id handled!");
            return null;
    }
}
```

I am making use of the CursorLoader which has different parameters than the  Cursor of SQLiteDatabase (I can see how the "distinct" parameter would be useful here)

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Thanks. Was able to mention that I am using the newer CursorLoader instead of the SQLite Cursor.

Comment: If you wrote the `ContentProvider`, you can define a URI for which it will return that distinct query.

Comment: So this will no longer be utilizing the CursorLoader and instead making a manual call through the URI?

Comment: No. I'm saying that instead of `DatabaseDescription.Flowers.CONTENT_URI`, you define a separate URI that your `ContentProvider`'s `query()` method will perform that distinct query for. You would still use the new URI with `CursorLoader`.

Comment: For this request I am actually retrieving from my SQLite Database. My URI currently points to my database table however I am not sure how to pass parameter such as Distinct into the query. Any examples of this or extra guidance is appreciated.